# Difference between geom_col() and geom_point() for same value

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, missing-data

So, I'm trying to plot missing values here over time (longitudinal data).
I would prefer placing them in a geom_col() to fill up with colours of certain treatments afterwards. But for some weird reason, geom_col() gives me weird values, while geom_point() gives me the correct values using the same function. I'm trying to wrap my head around why this is happening. Take a look at the y-axis.
Disclaimer:

- I know the missing values dissappear on day 19-20. This is why I'm making the plot.
- Sorry about the lay-out of the plot. Not polished yet.

For the geom_point:

```
gaussian_transformed %>% group_by(factor(time)) %>% mutate(missing = sum(is.na(Rose_width))) %>% ggplot(aes(x = factor(time), y = missing)) + geom_point()
```

Picture: geom_point

[image]

For the geom_col:

```
gaussian_transformed %>% group_by(factor(time)) %>% mutate(missing = sum(is.na(Rose_width))) %>% ggplot(aes(x = factor(time), y = missing)) + geom_col()
```

Picture: geom_col

[image]

Comment: welcome to SO. it is generally not a bad question - however, it would have helped to have a reproducible example - see my answer for one way to do this. There is hardly any problem that cannot be reproduced with fake data, and it helps us help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `mutate` and creating several rows for your groups. You cannot see that, but you will have plenty of points overlapping in your geom_point plot.

One way is to either use `summarise`, or you use `distinct`
Compare

```r
library(tidyverse)
msleep %>% group_by(order) %>% 
  mutate(missing = sum(is.na(sleep_cycle))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = order, y = missing)) + 
  geom_point()
```

The points look ugly because there is a lot of over plotting.
[image]

```r
msleep %>% group_by(order) %>% 
  mutate(missing = sum(is.na(sleep_cycle))) %>% 
  distinct(order, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = order, y = missing)) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image]

```r
msleep %>% group_by(order) %>% 
  mutate(missing = sum(is.na(sleep_cycle))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = order, y = missing)) + 
  geom_col()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!
Makes sense that the points are just plotted on top of each other. And they geom_col() summed them up. Didn't know about the distinct() function yet. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

So after some digging:

What happens was that the geom_col() function sums up all the missing values while geom_point() does not. Hence the large values for y. Why this is happening, I do not know. However doing the following worked fine for me:

```
gaussian_transformed$time <- as.factor(gaussian_transformed$time)
gaussian_transformed %>% group_by(time) %>% summarise(missing = sum(is.na(Rose_width))) -> gaussian_transformed
gaussian_transformed %>% ggplot(aes(x = time, y = missing)) + geom_col(fill = "blue", alpha = 0.5) + theme_minimal() + labs(title = "Missing values in Gaussian Outcome over the days", x = "Time (in days)", y = "Amount of missing values") + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10, 1))
```

With the plot: [GaussianMissing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt0x5.png)